# Delete Duplicates in Table with huge amount of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, duplicates

I have a table with 19 million records. I want to delete duplicates, but the query I am using is taking a very long while and eventually connection is timing out.

This is the query I am using:

```
DELETE FROM [TableName]
WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM [TableName] GROUP BY field)
```

where `ID` is Primary key and auto increment.
I want to delete the duplicates in `field`.

Is there a faster alternative to this query?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: speaking of duplicates, check this link, it should help.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Answer (score 2):

i suggest temporarily adding an index onto `field` to speed things up. maybe use this statement to delete (even though yours should work fine with the index).

my statement generates a list of ids that should be deleted. assuming that id as the primary key is indexed, this is probably faster. this should also perform a little better than `not in`.

```
with candidates as (
    SELECT id 
         , ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by field order by id desc) rn
      FROM [TableName]
)
delete 
  from candidates
 where rn > 1
```

Comment: You don't need to join `candidates`, you can directly delete *from* `candidates`.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a a spin on Brett Schneiders, with a batched approach (including a small wait) to avoid contention, and alleviate explosive log file growth.

Set your initial `@batchcount` to something you think the server can handle -- you can also increase/decrease the wait time as needed.  Once `@@ROWCOUNT=0`, the loop will terminate.

```
declare @batchcount int, @totalrows int
set @totalrows = 0
set @batchcount = 10000 -- set this to some initial value

while @batchcount > 0
begin
    ;with dupes as (
        SELECT id 
             , ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by field order by id desc) rownum
          FROM [TableName]
    )
    delete top (@batchcount) t1
      from TableName t1
      join dupes c
        on c.id = t1.id
       and c.rownum > 1

    set @batchcount = @@ROWCOUNT --record how many just got nuked
    set @totalrows = @totalrows + @batchcount --track progress
    print cast(@totalrows as varchar) + ' rows have been deleted' -- show progress
    waitfor delay '00:00:05' -- wait 5 seconds for log writes, other queries etc
end
```

The print statement may not "show" on every loop in SSMS, but every so often you'll see SQL messages appear showing hundreds of iterations completed... be patient.

Answer (score 0):

Create another heap table and insert there the ids you want to delete. Than delete the records in the main table (where exists in heap table) in chunks of 1000-5000 each to avoid the time out. Good luck!